# Convert JSON format column to new columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a sub-Yelp Dataset in csv, and attributes column is in json format. I'm trying to convert that column to new columns, but none of the relevant code on different question works for me.

Texts in the attributes column are in this format, in every row:

```py
bus = pd.read_csv('public3-business.csv')
bus.iloc[10:12,8:12]

stars  review_count  is_open                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  attributes
   4.0           603     True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              {"WiFi": "u'no'", "HasTV": "True", "Caters": "False", "Alcohol": "u'beer_and_wine'", "Ambience": "{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}", "NoiseLevel": "u'average'", "BikeParking": "True", "GoodForKids": "True", "GoodForMeal": "{'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': True, 'dinner': True, 'brunch': False, 'breakfast': False}", "OutdoorSeating": "False", "BusinessParking": "{'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}", "RestaurantsAttire": "'casual'", "RestaurantsTakeOut": "True", "RestaurantsDelivery": "False", "RestaurantsPriceRange2": "2", "RestaurantsReservations": "False", "RestaurantsTableService": "True", "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": "True", "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": "True"}
   4.5            84     True {"WiFi": "u'no'", "HasTV": "False", "Music": "{'dj': False, 'background_music': True, 'jukebox': False, 'live': False, 'video': False, 'karaoke': False}", "Caters": "False", "Alcohol": "u'beer_and_wine'", "Smoking": "u'no'", "Ambience": "{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}", "CoatCheck": "False", "HappyHour": "True", "BestNights": "{'monday': False, 'tuesday': False, 'friday': True, 'wednesday': False, 'thursday': True, 'sunday': False, 'saturday': True}", "NoiseLevel": "u'average'", "BikeParking": "True", "DogsAllowed": "False", "GoodForKids": "True", "GoodForMeal": "{'dessert': False, 'latenight': True, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': False, 'brunch': False, 'breakfast': False}", "GoodForDancing": "False", "OutdoorSeating": "False", "BusinessParking": "{'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}", "RestaurantsAttire": "u'casual'", "RestaurantsTakeOut": "True", "RestaurantsDelivery": "False", "WheelchairAccessible": "True", "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin": "False", "RestaurantsPriceRange2": "1", "RestaurantsReservations": "False", "RestaurantsTableService": "True", "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": "True", "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": "True"}
```

or, as plain text:

'{"WiFi": "u'no'", "HasTV": "False", "Caters": "False", "Alcohol": "u'full_bar'", "Ambience": "{'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romantic': True, 'divey': False, 'intimate': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'classy': False, 'casual': False}", "NoiseLevel": "u'average'", "BikeParking": "False", "GoodForKids": "False", "GoodForMeal": "{'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': True, 'brunch': False, 'breakfast': False}", "OutdoorSeating": "True", "BusinessParking": "{'garage': True, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': True}", "RestaurantsAttire": "u'dressy'", "RestaurantsTakeOut": "False", "RestaurantsDelivery": "False", "RestaurantsPriceRange2": "4", "RestaurantsReservations": "True", "RestaurantsTableService": "True", "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": "True", "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": "True"}'

As seen, f.e, Ambiance attribute also has subattributes like romantic, intimate etc.
I want to get columns for each attributes, like Wifi, HasTv, Ambianc.romantic etc.

```py
stars  review_count  is_open  HasTV  Alcohol  Ambiance.romantic  Ambiance.intimate   WiFi
   2.5            13    False   True    False              False               True  False
   4.0            25    False  False    False              False              False u'free
```

Does anyone know how to make this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you can access the json itself, `pd.json_normalize()` will be your friend here.

Comment: @BeRT2me Unfortunately. Why using .to_json and normalize it back not works? I wonder

Answer (score 0):

This gets you a step closer to what you want:

```
d = {"WiFi": "u'no'", "HasTV": "False", "Caters": "False", "Alcohol": "u'full_bar'", "Ambience": "{'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romantic': True, 'divey': False, 'intimate': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'classy': False, 'casual': False}", "NoiseLevel": "u'average'", "BikeParking": "False", "GoodForKids": "False", "GoodForMeal": "{'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': True, 'brunch': False, 'breakfast': False}", "OutdoorSeating": "True", "BusinessParking": "{'garage': True, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': True}", "RestaurantsAttire": "u'dressy'", "RestaurantsTakeOut": "False", "RestaurantsDelivery": "False", "RestaurantsPriceRange2": "4", "RestaurantsReservations": "True", "RestaurantsTableService": "True", "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": "True", "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": "True"}
pd.json_normalize(d)
```

Output:

```
    WiFi  HasTV Caters      Alcohol                                           Ambience  ... RestaurantsPriceRange2 RestaurantsReservations RestaurantsTableService RestaurantsGoodForGroups BusinessAcceptsCreditCards
0  u'no'  False  False  u'full_bar'  {'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romanti...  ...                      4                    True                    True                     True                       True

[1 rows x 19 columns]
```